# Cannot set ringtone

Tags: android, android-sqlite, mediastore, ringtone, android-music-player

I'm building a simple audio player. I have listed all songs from the sdcard and displayed it. I have given users the feature to set any of the songs as their device ringtone. But each time I set the ringtone, the ringtone of the device changes to "NONE". Yes, I have given the required permissions.

The app does not crash but gives me this error in the logcat:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting artist_id=126 bucket_id=1389444597 is_notification=false date_modified=1520074262 bucket_display_name=0 is_ringtone=true parent=0 format=12297 storage_id=65537 media_type=2 mime_type=audio/mp3 album_id=165 _size=9955517 _data=/storage/emulated/0/Akon - Forever (feat. Future) - 320 Kbps - (BossMp3.Me).mp3 title=My Song title is_music=false date_added=1520796971 is_alarm=false title_key=AYMEC5O9O?1 _display_name=Akon - Forever (feat. Future) - 320 Kbps - (BossMp3.Me).mp3
                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067)
```

Code:

```
 public void setRingtone(SongInfoModel song){


    if(song != null) {

        File k = new File(song.getData());

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                newUri
        );

    }
```

Comment: may be you need to change      `RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION` to `RingtoneManager. TYPE_RINGTONE ` for `setActualDefaultRingtoneUri` method

Comment: Tried that as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are inserting an item which already inserted in `MediaStore`. You are prompted for duplicate `_data` field inside error prompt `UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067)` and `_data` field according to log provided is:

```
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Akon - Forever (feat. Future) - 320 Kbps - (BossMp3.Me).mp3
```

May be having a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848511/unique-constraint-failed-when-trying-to-share-video-via-intent) and comments from @CommonsWare helps you.

Comment: I also guessed that and tried commented out this line `Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
Then I checked my ringtone, I could see the name of the audio file set as ringtone. But the name was not preset in the spinner(list of ringtones).

Comment: I deleted the item before inserting it and it worked fine.
            `context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);`

Comment: @Rektirino So the problem still exist or does it resolved?